# Errors due to vowpal wabbit's dependencies on boost library

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit, large-data

I'm trying real hard to install vowpal wobbit and it fails when i run the make file, throwing:

```
    cd library; make; cd .. 
    g++ -g -o ezexample temp2.cc -L ../vowpalwabbit -l vw -l allreduce -l boost_program_options -l z -l pthread 
    ld: library not found for -lboost_program_options collect2: ld returned 1   exit status make[1]: *** [ezexample] Error 1'
```

I then added the links to the boost library here by specifying -L/usr/local/lib

Now I get the following error:

```
    g++ -g -o ezexample temp2.cc -L/usr/local/lib ../vowpalwabbit -l vw -l  allreduce -l boost_program_options -l z -l pthread 
    ld: library not found for -lvw
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status   
    make: *** [ezexample] Error 1
```

Comment: This is (probably) better suited to SO. Voting to close.

Comment: I'm looking for people who've used vowpal wabbit, though.

Comment: Do you have a working `boost` installation? The `program_options` library should be built separately, if I remember correctly. Also, there should be no space after `-L` or `-l` switch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I happened to get everything working on OS X 10.7 as follows:

1. Make sure you have a working Boost installation. As indicated on the [Getting started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) page, usually we only need header files, but some Boost libraries must be built separately, including the [program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/program_options.html) library which is used to process options from command line or config file. Go into your `boost` folder, and then at your shell prompt:

   ```
   $ ./bootstrap.sh
   $ ./bjam
   ```

   This will compile and build everything. You should now have a `bin.v2/` directory in your `boost` directory, with all built libraries for your system (static and threaded libs).

   ```
   $ ls bin.v2/libs/
   date_time       iostreams       python          serialization   test
   filesystem      math            random          signals         thread
   graph           program_options regex           system          wave
   ```

   More importantly, extra Boost libraries are made available in the `stage/lib/` directory. For me, these are `Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`.

   The *include path* should be `your_install_dir/boost_x_xx_x`, where `boost_x_xx_x` is the basename of your working Boost. (I personally have `boost_1_46_1` in `/usr/local/share/` and I symlinked it to `/usr/local/share/boost` to avoid having to remember version number.) The *library path* (for linking) should read `your_install_dir/boost_x_xx_x/stage/lib`. However, it might be best to symlink or copy (which is what I did) everything in usual place, i.e. `/usr/local/include/boost` for header files, and `/usr/local/lib` for libraries.
2. Edit the `Makefile` from the `vowpal_wabbit` directory, and change the include/library paths to reflect your current installation. The `Makefile` should look like this (first 12 lines):

   ```
   COMPILER = g++
   UNAME := $(shell uname)

   ifeq ($(UNAME), FreeBSD)
   LIBS = -l boost_program_options -l pthread -l z -l compat
   BOOST_INCLUDE = /usr/local/include
   BOOST_LIBRARY = /usr/local/lib
   else
   LIBS = -l boost_program_options -l pthread -l z
   BOOST_INCLUDE = /usr/local/share/boost            # change path to reflect yours
   BOOST_LIBRARY = /usr/local/share/boost/stage/lib  # idem
   endif
   ```

   Then, you are ready to compile `vowpal_wabbit` (`make clean` in case you already compiled it):

   ```
   $ make
   $ ./vw --version
   6.1
   $ make test
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You can also install vowpal wabbit on OS X using [brew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew):

```
brew install vowpal-wabbit
```

Or you can just install boost, and then install `vw` from the github repo.

```
brew install boost
```

Comment: (+1) Yeh, that's what I did now that I definitely switched to Homebrew.

Comment: Are you able to use the vw-hypersearch utility if you install vowpal-wabbit with brew? I am getting an error stating "command not found," but the rest of vw works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For installation on CentOS 7 (6.5 perl version is too old for latest vw source code), I've found the instructions at http://wkoplitz.blogspot.be/2012/12/vowpal-wabbit-on-centos.html to work fine:

```
yum install zlib-devel boost-devel

yum groupinstall "Development Tools"

git clone git://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit.git

cd vowpal_wabbit

./autogen.sh

make

make test
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Good news:

As of the latest release VowpalWabbit version 9.1.0, vw no longer relies on Boost program_options

#### From the release highlights:

> Removal of Boost Program Options dependency
>
> For a long time we have depended on Boost Program Options
> for command line options parsing. In this release, we have > replaced this dependency with our own implementation of
> command line parsing. Apart from one place where we depend > on Boost Math in standalone mode, this means that VW core
> and the command line tool are free of Boost dependencies
> hopefully making the code a bit easier to build and package.

[Vowpal Wabbit 9.1.0 release notes](https://vowpalwabbit.org/blog/vowpalwabbit-9.1.0.html)